# How to find out if setTimeout is running on the background

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am having a problem to stop the setTimeout function fired previously.

I found some relative questions and the giving solution is to put the time_out variable outside of the function to make it work. I tried but still not working.

```
   this.A = function(){
        if(time_out) clearTimeout(time_out);  
        // time_out is nothing here and this will return error
        
        time_out = setTimeout(function(){  }, 3000);
    }
    
    -------------------------------------------------

     this.time_out = 0;
     this.A = function(){
          if(this.time_out) clearTimeout(this.time_out);  
          //will run through, but the setTimeout setup previously will keep running...
            
         this.time_out = setTimeout(function(){  }, 3000);
     }
```

---

#### Update

I tired put the whole function into a element and call it out when reset

```
if(el.data('time_out')) clearTimeout(el.data('time_out'));
```

This works perfect

Comment: You problem seems to be the context of `this`.

Comment: You could try declaring `time_out` as a global variable

Comment: @AlexW - Storing *anything* in a global variable is almost always bad advice.

Comment: I think we need more code to be able to tell what the problem is...

Comment: I also tried var time_out outside of this.A, will return undefined everytime running this.A

Comment: @JosephSilber I think *anything* is too strong of a word.  There are many cases where global variables are useful.

Comment: @AlexW - True; which is why I then qualified it with an *almost*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you are in the proper scope.

```
var timerFun = function(){
     var me = this;
     me.timer= undefined;

     me.startTimeout = function(){
        me.timer = setTimeout(me.SetterFunc, 3000);
     };

     me.setterFunc = function(){
        alert('oh hai!');
        me.ClearTimer();
     };

     me.clearTimer = function(){
        if(me.timer!= undefined){
            me.clearTimeout(me.timer);
        }
     };
     return me;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Create trigger functions for timeout

```
startTimeOut(){
started = 1;
setTimeout(yourFunction, 2000);
}
```

well then u can check if started=1  u can stop it and if started=0 means it is stopped

```
stopTimeOut(){
started = 0;
clearTimeout(yourFunction);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to stop a setTimeout.

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    myFunc();
}, 1000);

function myFunc(){
    //do something...
};
```

To clear the timeout

```
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Comment: the op asked how to test if a setimeout is running NOT how to stop one